# MomentJs design pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, momentjs

I really search a lot about that but I didn't find a suitable result.
I want to know, what's the `MomentJs` design pattern?

It's a little bit like `Module Pattern` but final public API exposed with `Prototype`:

In line 917: https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/master/moment.js#L917

```
moment.fn = Moment.prototype = ...
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the api design of moment.js was inspired by jQuery.

The constructor does not need the `new` keyword and accepts a variety of inputs.

`moment.fn` and `jQuery.fn` are both an exposure of the main prototype.

The getters and setters both use the same namespace, and act as getters or setters based on whether or not input was provide. `moment().date()` vs `moment().date(1)`, `$().height()` vs `$().height(200)`.

They both use method chaining, also known as the [fluent interface pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). `moment().date(1).month(5)` and `$().hide().addClass('something')`.